# Vue.js 3: How to get props value and use it in functions in script setup?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, tailwind-css, vue-composition-api, vue-script-setup

We all love vue 3 new script setup, but it is difficult to shift to it because of low usage and less support. I faced problem while getting and using props value inside functions.My code was like below

```
<script setup>
defineProps({
  text: String,
  howShow: Number,
  text1: String,
  text2: String,
  text3: String,
  widths: {
    type: String,
    default: "100%",
  },
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To access the data, you can simply use: `props.widths`

after defining your `props` in your child component:

```js
<script setup>
import { computed } from 'vue'
const props = defineProps({
  widths: {
    type: String,
    default: '100%',
  }
})
// do some stuff
// access the value by 
// let w = props.widths
</script>
```

in your template area you can access the value directly with `widths`:

```html
<div :style="{ width: widths }" />
```

Comment: In this case `w` will not be reactive, because getting a value from the `props` in root scope of `<script setup>` will cause the value to lose reactivity. See `vue/no-setup-props-destructure` lint rule.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this problem by doing this

```
<script setup>
import { toRefs } from "@vue/reactivity";
const props = defineProps({
  text: String,
  howShow: Number,
  text1: String,
  text2: String,
  text3: String,
  widths: {
    type: String,
    default: "100%",
  },
})
const { widths } = toRefs(props);
let getValue = () => {
  console.log("Getting Value");
  console.log(widths.value);
};
</script>
```

That All **Enjoy**

Comment: you can get the value by using `props.widths`

Comment: and instead of `{ widths } = toRefs(props)` you could also `widths = toRef(props, 'widths')` getting only the desired. see [toRef](https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-utilities.html#toref)